# Using java.util.zip to construct valid epub

Tags: java, zip, epub

I built a method that recursively adds the contents of a folder to a zip document with the file extension "epub," which is basically what an epub is except for one thing:

the first document in the archive must be named "mimetype," the type must be specified application/epub+zip, and must start with a byte offset of 38.  Is there a way to add the mimetype to the archive with offset 38?

The method I built nearly works.  It constructs an epub which can be read by most e-readers, but it doesn't validate.  EpubCheck gives this error:

```
mimetype contains wrong type (application/epub+zip expected)
```

This is an issue that does not exist in the original test epub, but shows up in the reconstructed epub.  And I double checked that the contents of the unzipped/rezipped mimetype file are correct.

The method is too much to post here.  But this is what I'm using to add the mimetype file to the archive:

```
out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFilename));

FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(mimeTypePath);
out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("mimetype"));

int len;
while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
   out.write(buf, 0, len);
}

out.closeEntry();
in.close();
out.close();
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you're reinventing the wheel rather than using existing libraries, such as http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib? Even if you don't end up using it, reading the source will tell you how it's properly done.

Comment: can you provide the procedure for creating epub zip in brief or suggest some tutorial?

Comment: @GAMA, your question might be better suited to a new topic here on stackoverflow. If you post the question, you'll most likely get the info you need. Depending on what you're attempting, I may have the answer you need. But it needs to be in a new topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to Wikipedia's description of the [Open Container Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB#Open_Container_Format_2.0.1), the `mimetype` file should be the first entry in the ZIP file, and it should be uncompressed.

Based on your sample code alone, it's not clear whether you're specifying that the `mimetype` file should be `STORED` (uncompressed).

The following seems to get me past the "mimetype contains wrong type" error:

```
private void writeMimeType(ZipOutputStream zip) throws IOException {
    byte[] content = "application/epub+zip".getBytes("UTF-8");
    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("mimetype");
    entry.setMethod(ZipEntry.STORED);
    entry.setSize(20);
    entry.setCompressedSize(20);
    entry.setCrc(0x2CAB616F); // pre-computed
    zip.putNextEntry(entry);
    zip.write(content);
    zip.closeEntry();
}
```

Confirmed: removing the `setMethod()`, `setSize()`, `setCompressedSize()` and `setCrc()` lines yields the "mimetype contains wrong type" error from `epubcheck`.